# Mongodb, linq driver. How to construct Contains with variable or statements

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the Mongo LINQ Driver for C#, works great.

Sorting a lot of properties but heres a problem I can't solve, its probably simple.

```
var identifierList = new []{"10", "20", "30"};
var newList = list.Where(x => identifierList.Contains(x.Identifier));

This is NOT supported ...
```

So I could do something like:

```
 var newList = list.Where(x => x.Identifier == "10" || x.Identifier == "20" || x.Identifier == "30");
```

But since the list is variable ... how do I construct the above? Or are there even better alternatives?

The `list` is of type `IQueryable<MyCustomClass>`

For information ... this is used as a filter of alot of properties. In SQL I could have a parent -> child relationship. But as I can't as the parent for the main ID I need to take all the ID's out and then construct it like this.

Hopes this makes sense. If needed I will explain more.

Comment: What are you trying to do? find if the list contains all of the items in another list? your code above (after a fix) will make that the items on newList will be the same items in list

Comment: Ups, bug in the example, will just fix that :-)

Comment: Still... not clear. try to explain in simple words what you are trying to achieve with the two lists operation. for example: i want to copy identifierList to newList (what i can assume from the code above)

Comment: Added more info. Should maybe have made clear that the first `list` is of complex elements ( classes not strings ) hence the Identifier property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question ... The Mongo Sharp LINQ driver has an extension method called "In" which does exactly what I need.

They have however implemented it in 1.5 so we can use the old way like: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-462

```
 var list = new []{"10", "10"};

 search.Where(x => list.Contains(x.Id));
```

But the version 1.5 package is not on nuget yet.

However, this should work with the "In" extension that comes as a special surprise with the mongo-csharp-driver.

```
 search.Where(x => x.In(list));
```

Comment: Your initial statement should have worked.  It simply wasn't implemented in 1.4.2.  1.5 will contain this feature. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-462

Comment: Yes, it should have worked, but since I use version 1.4.2 and not 1.5, I will have to use the last one. Most problems I discover with the LINQ provider have already been fixed :-). I do hope they will begin to make a pre-release :-).

Answer (score 0):

```
var identifierList = new []{"10", "20", "30"};
var newList = list.ToList().Where(x => identifierList.Contains(x.Identifier));
```

You will just have to use List instead of Ienumerable (do that by using the .ToList())

If it doesn't work please add your list TYPE

Comment: I'm trying to filter the list. Like get rid of all the MyCustomClass in the IQueryable<MyCustomClass> that dont have the Identifier property set to either "10", "20" or "30".

Comment: Unsupported where clause: Enumerable.Contains<String>(String[]:{ "10", "20", "30" }, x.Identifier).

Comment: Can you add your list initialization and declaration as well?

Comment: Its the mongodb-csharp driver that dont support "Contains". I looking for a solution by constructing it like a simple variable list in the Where clause.

Comment: Well ... could do that. But fetching 100.000 rows from Mongo, does not seem like a solid solution, but i agree, it would work.

Comment: so you can write a normal foreach loop without using .ToList, and maybe use a HashSet instead of identifierList

Comment: @eyossi no that would not solve the problem as it would be equal to using .ToList(). ToList()/foreach will materialize the queryable and load the data in memory. Your approach would filter only the in memory collection fetched from the database, which is not performant. The query should be done on the database level and therefore the linq query must be translateable to a query the mongo db understands